# NestJs + Swagger documentation based on versioning

Tags: nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

I have built a nestjs webapi and implemented versioning at controller and action level as per https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning

The solution i am looking into is, i want to generate 2 different swagger based on the controller version.
For example, i have 2 controller defined for 2 different version. if i hit [example.com/v1/swagger] , it should load only v1 version controller swagger doc and similarly for v2

Comment: did you check this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1495)? Is it relatable to your problem?

Comment: @wald3 : No.. I am looking for Swagger versioning aligned with nestjs versioning

Answer (score 4):

app.enableVersioning(); should be called before SwaggerModule.createDocument(...)

Source: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1495#issuecomment-898311614

Answer (score 3):

I recently updated my API to support versioning.  I couldn't get the Swagger docs to load correctly.  Here is my solution, I hope it helps!

Before, we had used `app.setGlobalPrefix(APP_ROUTE_PREFIX)` to define the prefix.

```
const APP_ROUTE_PREFIX = 'api/v2';
app.setGlobalPrefix(APP_ROUTE_PREFIX);
```

Swagger docs were mounted as:

```
SwaggerModule.setup(`${APP_ROUTE_PREFIX}/docs`, app, document);
```

To adopt versioning, the following was changed.

1. Route prefix no longer includes the version; let Nestjs handle it.

```
const APP_ROUTE_PREFIX = 'api';
```

2. Versioning is enabled, with a default of '2', mimicking previous behavior.

```
  app
    .enableVersioning({ type: VersioningType.URI, defaultVersion: '2' })
    .setGlobalPrefix(APP_ROUTE_PREFIX);
```

3. To get Swagger docs to mount correctly, we had to use a variable `:version` in the path.

```
  SwaggerModule.setup(`${APP_ROUTE_PREFIX}/:version/docs`, app, document);
```

4. Next, we changed on a per-controller basis the controllers that need to adopt versioning.

```
@Controller({ path: 'objects/:id', version: ['2', '3'] })
```

5. Finally, we changed on a per-route basis the handlers that support multiple versions.

```
  @Version('2')
  getPageV2(): Promise<Observable<unknown>> {
    return this.service.getOkayData();
  }

  @Version('3')
  getPageV3(): Promise<Observable<unknown>> {
    return this.service.getBetterData();
  }
```

Comment: Hey, what version of swagger are you using? I can't get this to work, path :version variable is just ignored, always get back everything

Comment: Our nestjs swagger version in package.json is `^5.1.5`

Comment: the :version is ignored always returns everything!

Comment: Not working for me. Always shows the latest version one on swagger.

Solved: The problem was that you need to setup versioning on app before swaggermodule setup